# Riak Search numFound inconsistency

Tags: solr, riak, nosql

My Riak  Search index somehow comes to inconsistent state, numFound show more items that  really was found.
I Was clear  my index and now it is show 34 phantom records:

```
solr/some_index/select?q=some_query&wt=json&rows=50

{
responseHeader: 
{
status: 0,
QTime: 47,
params: 
{
q: "some_query",
q.op: "or",
filter: "",
wt: "json"
}
},
response: 
{
numFound: 34,
start: 0,
maxScore: "0.353553",
docs: [ ]
}
}
```

I was manage my index only using the Solr HTTP Interface

1. Looks i got some broken records. How can i found and cleanup it?
2. How to prevent this one in future

I was try:

1. Reboot entire cluster( to eliminate in memory cache )
2. search-cmd delete my_index

=>no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like know issue, should use Riak 2.0 to fix

https://github.com/basho/riak/issues/547#issuecomment-44591963